# Any good example of search with dropdownlist using viewmodel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC and I want to create a search form with dropdownlist so user can select from categories. The dropdownlist is populated through database. As I have researched, this can be easily done using viewmodels but I am still confused on how to do it. Can anyone please provide me with links to good examples with clear explanations? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

look i made the same example before for locations i used this script that calls function to return JSON file with the result from Database so you can change the names
View:

```
        <div class="col-md-8">


           @Html.DropDownListFor(r=>r.locationID ,new SelectList(Model.Locations,"ID","Name"), new { @class = "form-control TowerLoc" ,id = "location", OnChange="ChangeContent()" })

             </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Tower</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">

 @Html.DropDownListFor(r=>r.TowerID, new SelectList(Model.Towers,"TowerID","TowerName"),new { @class = "form-control" , id="Towers"})
  </div>
     </div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    $("#location").change(function () {
        $("#Towers").find("option:gt(0)").remove();
        $("#Towers").find("option:first").text("Loading...");
        $.getJSON("/Inquiries/GetChildren", {
            parentid: $(this).val()
        }, function (json) {
            $("#Towers").find("option:first").remove();
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

                $("<option/>").attr("value", json[i].TowerID).text(json[i].TowerName).appendTo($("#Towers"));
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Function:

```
public JsonResult GetChildren(int parentID)
        {

            var children = (from g in _db.Towers.Where(r => r.ProvinceID == parentID).ToList()
                            select new Tower
                            {
                                TowerID = g.TowerID,
                                TowerName = g.TowerName
                            }).ToList();
            return Json(children, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: I think you got the wrong guy xD Anyways, I'm looking for a solution without using javascript yet. Thanks for the effort and I might be able to use this in the future.